# How can I store JSX in a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

This outputs correctly, works as JSX, highlights the field as expected.

```
var result = "the text";
renderResults[2].props.children.props.listing.title = <span className="highlight"> {result} </span>;
```

This one, however, does not. It displays as a string with the html tags:

```js
var result = "the text";
var finalResult = <span className="highlight"> {result} </span>;
renderResults[2].props.children.props.listing.title = finalResult;
```

How do I get the second to pass as JSX and not a string?

Comment: We need to see more code, please show a full [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I don't know why one is working and the other isn't, but you're missing a close quote on your `className` attribute in both

Comment: That assignment looks a bit confusing, doesnt it? Could you share you a bit more code, like your full component, so we can help?

Answer (score 1):

Your class attribute is missing closing quote

```
var finalResult = <span className="highlight"> {result} </span>;
```

Comment: It's missing in both examples, though...why does it work in one and not the other?

Comment: I think JSX parser could answer that.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close className, maybe that is the reason why it doesn't work.

className="highlight"

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typo on your code, you are missing a `"` after `className="highlight>`

A working example:

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const result = "the text";
  const finalResult = <span className="highlight"> {result} </span>;
  
  return finalResult;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo/>, document.getElementById('demo'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Please explain what's wrong in the OP's question, and what you did in your example that makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm mistaken, but as mentioned per docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks)

> By default, React DOM escapes any values embedded in JSX before rendering them. Thus it ensures that you can never inject anything that’s not explicitly written in your application. Everything is converted to a string before being rendered. This helps prevent XSS (cross-site-scripting) attacks.

So it assumes that your variable is user input or something malicious and escapes it before using it's content, while in the second example, you're explicitly assigning JSX to a variable so it works.

Comment: so how is this fixed so it sees it as JSX?

Comment: Inline as `x = JSX`, or return it from a function `() => <span></span>`

Comment: don't see how this is possible, the location of the span will not remain constant and will sometimes have more then one occurrence

Comment: I think you've come to a problem where you ended up with your solution and trying to make it work instead of posting your original problem as [stated](https://xyproblem.info/)